# Android Universal image loader with custom base image down-loader always gives total size as 51200

Tags: android, uiimageview, universal-image-loader

Hi I am building small android application in which I am using Universal image loader. I am using custom down loader class: It looks like as follow:

```
public class CustomUniversalImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param context
     */
    public CustomUniversalImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getStream(String imageUri, Object extra) throws IOException {
        switch (Scheme.ofUri(imageUri)) {
            case HTTP:
            case HTTPS:
                // here is my code ...

                    return new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent(), BUFFER_SIZE);

            case FILE:
                return getStreamFromFile(imageUri, extra);
            case CONTENT:
                return getStreamFromContent(imageUri, extra);
            case ASSETS:
                return getStreamFromAssets(imageUri, extra);
            case DRAWABLE:
                return getStreamFromDrawable(imageUri, extra);
            case UNKNOWN:
            default:
                return getStreamFromOtherSource(imageUri, extra);
        }
    }
```

On Displaying image I am doing following:

```
ImageCache.loader.displayImage(url, view, ImageCache.options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                                                    FailReason failReason) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {



                        }
                    }, new ImageLoadingProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgressUpdate(String imageUri, View view, int current,
                                                     int total) {

            // here my total always coming as 512000
                            Debug.print("inside this is image loading progress "+current+"  this is total ... "+total);
                            Debug.print("inside this is image loading progress "+Math.round(100.0f * current / total));

                        }
                    }
            );
        }
```

So if I use default Base Image Downloader then it works fine. But If I use custom one then it is giving image total length always 512000. Am I missing anything?
Need Some Help. Thank you.

Comment: i can't see where are you using CustomUniversalImageDownloader in UIL

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        ...
        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageLoaderCustom())
        ...
        .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

from Nostra:
[How set custom downloader in Universal Image Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164340/how-set-custom-downloader-in-universal-image-loader)

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I looks it into BaseImageLoader and it is doing following thing:

```
ContentLengthInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(entity.getContent(), BUFFER_SIZE), (int)entity.getContentLength());
```

It works fine.